# How to get p5js video to play in HTML using frames. It shows the graphics that I made in p5 but won't display the video capture element

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, p5.js

I am trying to put a p5js video in my HTML with iframes and the video will not play but I can see the frame of the canvas and graphics from p5.

It won't even ask for permission to use camera.

I tried making the video element in html. I don't know how to get the video to stream

## Change part 1

the graphics play from p5 but the video capture does not stream in html. 
It works perfect on the p5js preview.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to ask a more specific question and include code.

Comment: how can it be more specific. I put p5js iframes into html and the video capture element does not work. this is the p5 code createCanvas(1120, 900);
  capture = createCapture(VIDEO);
  capture.size(1120, 900);
   capture.hide();